# how to make a full screen layout in android?

Tags: android

I tried this code.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
        final WindowInsetsController insetsController =getWindow().getInsetsController();
        if(insetsController!=null){
            insetsController.hide(WindowInsets.Type.statusBars());
        }else
        {
           getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        }
    }
```

But , it not worked.

how to make a full screen layout in android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your custom theme by using default theme, like this

window with `Fullscreen`

```
<style name="generalnotitle" parent="general">
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
</style>
```

window with `NoTitle`

```
<style name="generalnotitle" parent="general">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Following works for me to make a full screen activity:

In styles

```
 <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
```

In manifest add this to the activity you want to make full screen

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
```

Answer (score 0):

If your compile SDK version to 30

// Tell the window that we (the app) want to handle/fit any system
// windows (and not the decor)

```
window.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(false)
```

// OR you can use WindowCompat from AndroidX v1.5.0-alpha02

```
WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
```

Comment: They've provided new api in new sdk 30. You can check out it here https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/animating-your-keyboard-fb776a8fb66d.